# How to read input from the user without breaking the line afterward?

Tags: rust, terminal, newline

I am trying to achieve the following behaviour:

```
prompt> userEntersThis is a ...
prompt> userEntersThisAgain is a ...
```

where `prompt>`  and the trailing  `is a ...\n` are inline `print!`ed by code while `userEntersThis` is user input, meant to be read via `read_line`. However, the read causes a linefeed leading to

```rust
prompt> userEntersThis 
 is a ...
prompt> userEntersThisAgain
 is a ...
```

How to perform inline `print` after a read_line?
Maybe `read_line` isn't the way to go.

**Code**

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    loop {
        print!("prompt> ");
        io::stdout().flush().expect("couldn't flush");
        let mut str = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut str).expect("couldn't read");
        print!(" is a ...\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: on unix-like systems (and possibly windows, I'm not sure) stdin is line-buffered by default. This means that your program won't receive any input until at least one line has been entered (i.e. user has pressed enter). So at a minimum, you probably need to change that behavior.

Comment: If you want this specific behavior, you'd have to use a terminal library like [crossterm](https://crates.io/crates/crossterm) or [termion](https://crates.io/crates/termion) though they can of course do much more than this.